# How can I create a folder if it doesn't exist, from .vimrc?

Tags: vim

I don't like how Vim clutters up my folders with backup files, so I have the following line in my .vimrc file:

```
set backupdir=~/.vim_backup
```

However, sometimes this folder doesn't exist because of new machines where I am copying my user files over.

How can I create this folder automatically if it doesn't exist, from within .vimrc? Or is there some better way to deal with this situation?

Comment: vim has the builtin function `isdirectory(your_path)`.  Also you could have vim delegate to the shell: `let directory_exists = system("test -d $YOURDIR; echo $?")`. As with all issues of files/directories, Watchout for hard/soft symbolic links, mounted drives, race conditions and read permissions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can put this into your .vimrc:

```
silent !mkdir ~/.vim_backup > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This will attempt to create the ~/.vim_backup each time you start vim. If it already exists, mkdir will signal an error, but you'll never see it.

Comment: +1: Good answer.  Assuming Linux, you could also do `!mkdir -p ~/.vim_backup` as the `-p` option will stop mkdir reporting an error in the first place (as well as making parent directories if required).

Comment: Why do you do `!mkdir`? There is built-in vim function `mkdir()` which serves same purpose and is more portable. More, your code without surrounding `if` is doing an unnecessary shell call which slows down startup.

Comment: @ZyX yeah, so the question is: how do you detect whether a folder exists? I know filereadable(), is there an equivalent for folders?

Comment: EDIT: I have just RTFM, there is `isdirectory()`. Will edit the answer soon.

Comment: @barraponto You don’t need to check, whether path is a directory, you need to check whether it exists. This is a different construct: `empty(glob('~/.vim_backup'))`. It will catch the cases “path is a directory” (also caught by `isdirectory()`, “path is a readable file” (also caught by `filereadable()`) and also “path is unreadable file” (caught by nothing else). In all three cases `mkdir()` will fail.

Comment: so, in this case, which one should I use? I'm also defining `undodir`.

Comment: This solution slows down vim startup by **460ms** for me! The `mkdir()` vimscript solution causes no slowdown at all. (My setup: macOS Mojave, iTerm2 3.2.5, fish 2.7.1, nvim 0.3.1.)

Answer (score 98):

I think this is operating system independent:

```
if !isdirectory("/my/directory")
    call mkdir("/my/directory", "p")
endif
```

Comment: but in that case you have to use $HOME instead of ~
`silent !mkdir ~/.vim_backup > /dev/null 2>&1`
will become
`silent call mkdir ($HOME.'/.vim_backup', 'p')`

Answer (score 13):

You could use the [`mkdir()`](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-en/builtin.html#mkdir()) Vim function. It can create intermediate directories and set proper permissions on the directory as well:

```
if !isdirectory($HOME . "/.vim/backup")
    call mkdir($HOME . "/.vim/backup", "p", 0700)
endif
```

Comment: Just curious... I tried this solution, but `~/.vim/somepath/` doesn't quite work as it works the full path instead of the `~`. Anyway, once I figured that, it worked as a charm.

Answer (score 11):

I much prefer the one-liners already posted. However, I thought I'd share what I've been using:

```
function! EnsureDirExists (dir)
  if !isdirectory(a:dir)
    if exists("*mkdir")
      call mkdir(a:dir,'p')
      echo "Created directory: " . a:dir
    else
      echo "Please create directory: " . a:dir
    endif
  endif
endfunction

call EnsureDirExists($HOME . '/.vim_backup')
```

Comment: The "Created" message could be false if `mkdir` throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a solution to this that works on both Linux and on Windows (with Cygwin binaries on the path.) - my Vim config is shared between the two.

One problem is that 'mkdir' is, I think, built-in to the cmd shell on windows, so it can't be overridden by putting the Cygwin mkdir executable earlier in the path.

I solved this by invoking a new bash shell to perform the action: From there, 'mkdir' always means whatever mkdir executable is on the path:

```
!bash -c "mkdir -p ~/.vim-tmp"
```

However, this has the problem that. on Windows at least, it pops up a new window for the cmd shell that '!' invokes. Don't want that every time I start vim. Then I discovered the vim function 'system', which invokes a new cmd shell (the icon appears in the Windows taskbar) but the window is minimised. Hence:

```
call system("bash -c \"mkdir -p ~/.vim-tmp\"")
```

Ugly but works.

Comment: Look at @xer0x answer, you can check if the directory exists and only then call system, making your solution ugly but as practical as possible on a window host.

Answer (score 1):

I have a command in my [vimrc](https://github.com/phildobbin/PortableVim/blob/master/.vimrc) that enables me to make a directory corresponding to the buffer presently frontmost:

`nmap <silent> ,md :!mkdir -p %:p:h<CR>`

This can be used to create a directory any place you care to put one locally or remotely via netrw if you the permissions to do so.

Comment: Hey. What precisely does 'corresponding to' mean? Not 'named the same as', that doesn't quite make sense to me. So what?

Comment: You can find out by doing `:!echo %:p:h`.
It's basically the path for the file of the buffer that's currently "active"

(**Very** late to the party, but adding none the less ^-^)

Answer (score 0):

This is built into Vim, so you can simply:

```
call mkdir($HOME . "/tmp")
```

You can also specify the `p` flag to have the command operate in the same way `mkdir -p` would:

```
call mkdir($HOME . "/tmp", "p")
```

For details see `:help mkdir` or [the vim manual online](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#mkdir()).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am currently using in my .vimrc file and I think it looks quite clean and simple:

```
if empty(glob($HOME . '/.vim/undodir'))
  call mkdir($HOME . '/.vim/undodir', 'p')
endif
```