# Using Vim's persistent undo?

Tags: vim, undo, undo-redo

One of the new features in Vim 7.3 is 'persistent undo', which allows for the undotree to be saved to a file when exiting a buffer.

Unfortunately, I haven't quite been able to get it properly enabled, or I must be using it wrong.  Here's what I've tried so far:

I added the following to ~/.vimrc

```
set undofile                " Save undos after file closes
set undodir=$HOME/.vim/undo " where to save undo histories
set undolevels=1000         " How many undos
set undoreload=10000        " number of lines to save for undo
```

After this, I supposedly should be able to open any file, edit it, then save-close it, and when I open it again I should be able to undo/redo as if I'd never left.  Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the case, as no undofile is ever written.

Notes:

1. I'm on Win 7 using Vim 7.3 from the Vim without cream project. Persistent undo is baked-in.
2. $HOME/.vim/undo exists on my file system

Comment: Just to stress, point 2) is **very** important. Vim will not create the directory for you and persistent undo will not work until you `mkdir ~/.vim/undo`

Comment: +1. Sorry, on Linux it works... thanks for telling me about it!

Comment: For any future visitors to this question: Do **NOT** put quotes around the value of undodir! I got stuck on this problem for a while - use an absolute paht, without quotes around it.

Answer (score 60):

Put this in your `.vimrc` to create an `undodir` if it doesn't exist and enable persistent undo. Tested on both Windows and Linux.

```
" Put plugins and dictionaries in this dir (also on Windows)
let vimDir = '$HOME/.vim'

if stridx(&runtimepath, expand(vimDir)) == -1
  " vimDir is not on runtimepath, add it
  let &runtimepath.=','.vimDir
endif

" Keep undo history across sessions by storing it in a file
if has('persistent_undo')
    let myUndoDir = expand(vimDir . '/undodir')
    " Create dirs
    call system('mkdir ' . vimDir)
    call system('mkdir ' . myUndoDir)
    let &undodir = myUndoDir
    set undofile
endif
```

Comment: This may be preferable for creating the directory: `:silent call system('mkdir -p ' . &undodir)`

Comment: I use `&` because I `set` the `undodir` rather than `let`ting it. (In my mind this distinction between `let` and `set` is one of the many, many, many mind-bogglingly awful "features" of Vimscript, but YMMV.)

Comment: Thanks Kyle, it's a good idea to create `.vim` if it doesn't exist. Unfortunately the `-p` flag doesn't exist on Windows so I edited the answer to call `mkdir` twice to ensure Windows compatibility.

Comment: Ah. My primary reason for using the `-p` flag is actually to avoid an error when the directory exists. I have my command inside an `if has('win32')` block, so I just use `mkdir` without `-p` on Windows.

Comment: Why not use [`mkdir()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#mkdir%28%29)? Then this can become: `call mkdir(myUndoDir, 'p')`, which behaves like `mkdir -p`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @nelstrom. `call mkdir(myUndoDir, 'p')` gives me an error (probably because the directory already exists): `Cannot create directory: C:\Users\me\.vim\undodir`

Comment: @MatthiasBraun I just realised that the documentation for `mkdir()` is different in [Vim](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#mkdir%28%29) and [Neovim](https://neovim.io/doc/user/eval.html#mkdir%28%29). When I suggested this I had been looking at Neovim's documentation, which states that: "If you try to create an existing directory with {path} set to "p" mkdir() will silently exit.". Apparently this is not the case in Vim. My bad!

Comment: @nelstrom That's an excellent modification. Thanks. (The answer to your "why not" question is "because I didn't know that existed.")

Comment: Related: [How can I create a folder, if it doesn't exist, from .vimrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549263/1333025).

Answer (score 8):

I tried this in my _gvimrc:

```
" Persistent undo
try 
    set undodir=C:\vim\undodir
    set undofile
catch
endtry
```

It started working as advertised when I deleted the try-catch bracket, thus:

```
" Persistent undo
set undodir=C:\vim\undodir
set undofile
```

I had to create the directory.

Comment: `if has('persistent_undo')`

Comment: `silent !mkdir ~/.config/nvim/backups > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: `set undodir=~/.config/nvim/backups`

Comment: `endif` " adding commented message to increase message length

Comment: What is the point of has('persistent_undo')? Why do I need it? When is it true? When is it false?

Comment: has('persistent_undo') returns true if the vim instance it's running on was compiled with the persistent undo option. 
It's useful in case you use the same vimrc in diverse environments.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose $HOME doesn't work as advertised.

On my system, `:echo $HOME` shows H:\, but `: e $HOME/` says: `~/` invalid filename.

You could try with an absolute path to see whether it cures it

Comment: I could |:echo $HOME| and |:e $HOME/| without problems, but I tried changing things anyways.  It seemed to work at times, and not at others.  Particularly, it never saves backups when I'm editing my ~/.vimrc file.

Comment: On windows 7 I'm using `$TEMP`. When I look `set undodir?` it shows `~/AppData/Local/Temp`. Undo file is persisted and loads itself correctly. Maybe `$TEMP` will be more reliable?

Comment: In linux ~ is a shortcut for $HOME in the commandline, as you already know. 
About it working sometimes, I _guess_ that it might depend on which environment you start vim from. 
I imagine that it would work inside the mini shell that comes with git installations, but might not be recognized in a plain Windows shell. 
Cannot test, don't run Windows any more.
Perhaps with H:\  ...

Answer (score 1):

This now works as expected: `file.txt` open in a Vim 7.4 buffer on Windows 7, `:setlocal undofile`, then save a change to the buffer, and the undofile `.file.txt.un~` is created alongside because `:set undodir?` reports that "undodir=." by default - ie no need to specify this manually. You can also `:set undofile` in a modeline.