# remember last editing histories even after quitting

Tags: vim

I want to be able to undo the changes after I did `:wq` in `vim`. Is it possible?

I found it always complains `"Already at oldest change"` when I did `u`.

Comment: See also [Using vim's persistent undo?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5700389)

Answer (score 2):

Quick search in vim's help suggests that the `undofile` option might be of interest. Look for `undo-persistence` in the internal help.