# How to make a new directory and a file in Vim

Tags: vim

When using Vim as a text editor, is there a way to create new directories and files, while in text editor mode? Instead of going back to the command line and creating a new directory and file.

Comment: Sort of a cross-network duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/285500/how-to-run-unix-commands-from-within-vim

Comment: Are you looking for a one-liner to create files in a subdirectory that does not yet exist, or were you just unaware you could run shell commands without exiting vim? :)

Comment: Also [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549263/1333025) describe how to do this using vim's system calls. This is useful if you want to have such commands in your `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Assuming you're running a shell, I would shell out for either of these commands. Enter command mode with <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and then:

```
:! touch new-file.txt
:! mkdir new-directory
```

A great plugin for these actions is [vim-eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch), which gives you syntactic sugar for shell commands. Here's the latter example, using vim-eunuch:

```
:Mdkir new-directory
```

Comment: This answer is truth indeed, but it assumes running a shell. Check my answer below for pure-vim solution

Comment: I like this approach, but how do you use the current path? If you `vim ~/some/path` then `:! mkdir new_dir`, that will create `~/new_dir` instead of `/some/path/new_dir`.

Answer (score 126):

If you are in the file explorer mode, you can use:

> `d` for creating a directory
>
> `%` for creating a new file

You can get into the explorer mode with issuing a command `:Sexplore` or `:Vexplore`

There is no need to call external commands with `!`

Comment: To open explorer mode in vim use `:Sexplore` or `:Vexplore`.

Comment: This works nicely. I just wish there was a way to do this in bulk. Not even `vidir` provides a convenient way for my use case.

Answer (score 65):

Switch to file browsing mode

`:Ex` or if that is not working use `:Explore`

then press

`d`

and add the new directory name.

Comment: that does not exists

Comment: @PedroLuz Could you be please a bit more specifix what was not working for you? :Ex is shorthand for :Explore please have a look in vim help ```help :Explore```

Answer (score 53):

Assuming you just ran vim on new file in the directory that does not exist:

```
vim new_dir/new_file.txt
```

When you try :w you will get 'E212: Can't open file for writing'
To create new directory and file use this:

```
:!mkdir -p %:h
```

Comment: Works perfect, especially if you add a shortcut/ function for that

Comment: I was wonderin, what exactly `%:h` means: `%`: The name of the file (argument to vim). `:h`: Everything except the last component. Documented here: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file

Answer (score 10):

For the sake of completeness:

- Shell out and use normal commands, such as `:!mkdir my_dir` and `:!touch foo.txt` (as mentioned in [Jake's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37352091/728675)) will create the directory and file in CURRENT working directory, which is the directory when you started your current vim process in the beginning, but NOT NECESSARILY the same directory of the file that you are currently editing, or the same directory that your `:Explore` explorer is currently viewing. When in doubt, always use `:!pwd` to check your current working directory first, and use relative path when necessary.
- So if your project contains multiple sub-directories, a more convenient way is to:

  1. type `:Explore` to enter the explorer mode first,
  2. and then you can easily navigate to whatever sub-directory you like, by typing <kbd>up-arrow</kbd> or <kbd>down-arrow</kbd> (or <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd>) to move cursor, typing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter a sub-directory, typing <kbd>-</kbd> to go up a level of directory. (Note that, all these navigation does NOT change your current working directory either);
  3. Now you can type <kbd>d</kbd> to be prompted for a directory name, or type <kbd>%</kbd> to be prompted for a file name, and then they will be created in the directory currently shown on screen.
     PS: These keys are actually mentioned in the built-in help <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: This is the correct answer, you can use shell commands in Vim, but also just pure Vim.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you can use `:e .` to get to explorer mode and then hit `d` .to create the new directory .Thought a shorter answer might be better